# MAC address to binary bits conversion

Tags: python, binary, mac-address, hex

I am trying to convert a mac address,

```
mac = '00:de:34:ef:2e:f4'
```

into binary format. And the program i am using is,

```
mac = '00:de:34:ef:2e:f4'
r = mac.replace(':', '').decode('hex')  
print r
```

But i am getting a strange output when i run this program, and the output is

$Ã$

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: printing binary is going to look like strange characters

Comment: when you print it, the terminal (or console, or whatever) will try to interpret the binary as ASCII character codes (or whatever your native character set is) ... in this case, it is failing. What do you _want_ the output to look like?

Comment: my output should look like 00111000110100110101101010.....like that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think you want to use `decode`, that does unicode conversion and other stuff you don't want.  Just do:

```
n = int(mac.replace(':', ''), 16)
```

Which will convert your mac address to a number.  Print it with `'%012x'%n` to get the hex back.

**Edit:**

If you want to convert to binary, then just do `bin(n)`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a mac address with :

```
":".join(textwrap.wrap("%012x" % (integer), width=2))
```